# numpy multiply rows with subsequent rows of an array using product values of the previous row as input

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Assume to have the below numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
array_a = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

How can I iteratively multiply the previous row with the subsequent row without using any loop (the value of the previous row, except row=0, being the product of the multiplication).

The desired output for the above `array_a` would be

```
[[1,   2,  3
 [4,  10, 18]
 [28, 80, 162]]
```

I am aware of numpy matrix multiplication function like `np.dot` and `np.einsum` but I am not able to frame my problem in a way to use those functions. A solution in pandas, if any, is also welcome. Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: `numpy.cumprod`?

Comment: yup, this is what I was looking for, I tired np.prod but was not aware of this function. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`np.cumprod` is a great option if you only need to multiply.

```
import numpy as np
array_a = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
array_b = np.cumprod(array_a, axis=0)
```

Another option which is pretty efficent, is to use a generator.
This is a just a little bit slower, but also more versatile

```
def generator(arr):
    cnt_up = len(arr)
    cnt_down = 0

    if cnt_down == 0:
        yield arr[0]

    while cnt_up > 1:
       cnt_up -= 1
       cnt_down += 1
       yield arr[cnt_down-1] * arr[cnt_down]

gen = generator(array_a)
array_b = np.stack([g for g in gen])
```

Last option is to use recursion for other operations
(which will be much much slower slower, so `np.cumpcrod`/generator is preferred)

```
import numpy as np

array_a = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)


def recursive(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    else:
        return arr[-1] * recursive(arr[:-1])


array_b = np.stack([recursive(array_a[:i])[0] for i in range(1, len(array_a)+1)])
```

The second way is if you want to use a different custom formula.

Using `%timeit` I obtained the following results:

- 3 nano sec for cumpcrod,
- 9 nano sec for the generator option,
- 25 nano secs for the recursion

Comment: thanks @masasa for your efforts, i was particularly looking for a solution without having to resort to loops. your solutions still use looping which becomes less and less efficient as the array size increases.